# getting the states of selected country on logcat but not able to display on second spinner

Tags: android, spinner

i have two spinner one is for country and the second one is for state and i wanted to display selected state when particular country got selected am getting the selected country states printed on logcat but not able to display on second spinner

pls help me ???

Comment: Could you post some of your code? How are you populating the second spinner after the first has a selection?

Comment: i am getting response frm webserver......

Comment: Without the code we are not able to help.

Comment: You should really post the relevant code snippets - and the stack trace if you have any - otherwise we cannot figure out which of the dozen^n possible problems are you actually facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the selection listener of the first spinner, call a function to populate the second spinner with the list of states that belong to the country that was picked in the first spinner.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question

I think it should be something like this

```
public void fillSecondSpinner(){
if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().equals("some data"){
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arArgang = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.argang_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        arArgang.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(arArgang);
```

But there is no action